# How to get value from apex:inputCheckbox inside apex:repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a list - house and I am displaying it on a table using apex:repeat. In this table, I want a user input checkbox which I have implemented using apex:inputCheckbox.

```
<td><apex:inputCheckbox id="CeilingHeightCostCheckbox" value="{!house.CeilingHeightCostCheck}" selected="true" disabled="{!IF(house.Pckg_Ground_Floor_Ceiling_Height_Cost != 0, false, true)}" onchange="CeilingHeightCostCheckChange"/></td>
```

I am trying to check the user picked state of this inputCheckbox inside javascript using -

```
  var CheckboxState = $('[id$=CeilingHeightCostCheckbox]').is(':checked');
```

This is working fine if I just have 1 row in the list but when there are more than 1 rows, its giving random results. I guess because there are more than 1 checkboxes with id - `CeilingHeightCostCheckbox` how can I generate unique ids in this scenario or if there is another way to show checkbox and capture its state ? Please help.

Comment: I would look into using a wrapper class for capturing list through checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the method as:

```
function CeilingHeightCostCheckChange(event) {
  if(event.target.checked) {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

All events that are fired from an element have a `target` that identifies the element that fired the event, so you don't need to query the element again.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox ....I captured the checkbox state using above code and passed list Id as an argument to store it on the wrapper and that worked for me.